# Code review options for Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

We use Mercurial as our code repository. Currently we are manually reviewing the code changes and all the developers are directly committing into main branch (single branch).

Please suggest possible ways of code review or any tool which can be used with mercurial.

Comment: You didn't really explain what your "ideal" or best possible code review approach would be. What are you expecting the tools to do for you?

Comment: Do you need automatic things to happen?

Comment: For me, this is a good question. You can either use topics together with a non-publishing central-repo (see https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/tutorials/topic-tutorial.html) or use (a self hosted instance of) heptapod (https://about.heptapod.host/).

Comment: You could use RhodeCode: https://rhodecode.com/  Self-hosted and cloud-hosted options are available.